# How do we promote our site?

Tags: discussion, top-7

One of the big 7 questions.

- One sugestion per answer, please

Answer (score 16):

**Comments on off-topic questions on Stack Overflow.** There are lots of questions that pop up on Stack Overflow that would be better suited here. Using comments as a vehicle to promote this might be a good way to funnel traffic to its appropriate place in lieu of having a *Migrate to Programmers* close option.

Answer (score 9):

**Word of mouth.** I'm at school now, but I'm planning on telling everyone I know who might be interested in this to check it out when it enters public beta. I'll probably also shoot an email to some old coworkers of mine, Tweet interesting questions, etc.

Answer (score 7):

"Like/Share" type links for various social networks? I have a many people on social networks that I would like to spread this to.

This probably exists somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it

Answer (score 6):

**SEO** - ask good questions and give better than wikipedia answers that are relevant and likely to get linked up to lot's of blogs.

If you really want to advertise the site, you've got to make the internet better.

Of course this is just a ruse to put Mr. Rock Hard Awesome through Stanford.  But I don't care, it's fun.

Comment: +1 The best way to promote this site is just to *use it*, and let Google do its job.